# Java: Unable to read image file

Tags: java, image, exception

I am trying to load an png using this code:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource(fileName).toString());
```

The file exists, in the directory exists, I have used this numerous times to load files.
I am using eclipse and the classpath is configured, but for some reason I get this exception:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

This same code works in another project... I really don't know whats going on...

Comment: I'd start with looking at getClass().getResource(fileName).toString() output.

Comment: Is the file readable? is the image well-formed?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Either you want to load a resource from the classpath, or a file from the file system, but not both at the same time. Decide which one you want.

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid trying to read using a `File` at all - just use the `URL` returned by `getResource`:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(fileName));
```

Aside from anything else, that will still work when the resource is in a jar file, whereas it won't if you try to use `File`.